# MySQL - Embedded selects - How to put rows into columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Good Morning, I am facing a odd built database and i am trying to requesting it.

My request :

```
use redmine_tma_ibp;
SELECT issues.id, custom_fields.name, custom_values.value FROM       redmine_tma_ibp.issues
join custom_values 
    on issues.id = custom_values.customized_id
join custom_fields 
    on custom_values.custom_field_id = custom_fields.id
join enumerations 
    on enumerations.id=issues.priority_id
where (enumerations.type="IssuePriority" and (enumerations.position=1 or enumerations.position=2))
    and (status_id=3 or status_id=5)
    and (custom_fields.name = "Date de résolution" or custom_fields.name="Date d'ouverture")
    and str_to_date(custom_values.value, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') > date('2016-01-01');
```

it displays the following :

```
13430   Date de résolution  20/01/2016 16:52:27
14336   Date de résolution  04/01/2016 16:07:06
15705   Date d'ouverture    02/01/2016 00:28:46
15705   Date de résolution  04/01/2016 11:11:04
15774   Date d'ouverture    05/01/2016 11:15:06
15774   Date de résolution  05/01/2016 15:55:43
15790   Date d'ouverture    05/01/2016 16:24:20
15790   Date de résolution  06/01/2016 10:42:28
15917   Date d'ouverture    07/01/2016 16:04:31
15917   Date de résolution  07/06/2016 11:43:08
15955   Date d'ouverture    11/01/2016 02:21:48
15955   Date de résolution  12/01/2016 11:19:21
15998   Date de résolution  13/01/2016 10:35:29
```

I need to transform my request in order to have one column with the "Date d'ouverture" and another with the "Date de résolution", corresponding dates inside corresponding columns and grouped by id.

I cannot change the database structure which is read only.

Please help me....

Comment: You need a so-called pivot query. Read this about this concept: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pivot :

```
SELECT issues.id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN custom_fields.name='Date de résolution'
       THEN custom_values.value
   ELSE '-'
   END) AS 'Date de résolution',
   MAX(CASE WHEN custom_fields.name='Date d\'ouverture'
       THEN custom_values.value
   ELSE '-'
   END )AS 'Date d\'ouverture'
FROM [....]
GROUP BY issues.id
```

I use the trick with MAX() for the group by.

Comment: Result is two columns with either a data in one or in another. How can i have merge the results of the duplicate id numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT issues.id,
CASE
WHEN custom_fields.name = "Date d'ouverture" THEN custom_values.value END AS Date_d_ouverture,
WHEN custom_fields.name = "Date de résolution" THEN custom_values.value END AS Date_de_résolution
FROM
(your_query) sub
```